# Rails Route Constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

```
match '/:question_id', :to => 'welcome#dashboard', :via => [:get], constraint: { question_id: /\d+/ }
```

I don't know why this routing rule is matching paths like

localhost/assets

because I added the numeric constraint to only matching digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is `contstraints`.

```
match '/:question_id', :to => 'welcome#dashboard', :via => [:get], constraints: { question_id: /\d+/ }
```